# Open a file with spaces in the name in Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, file

How do you open a file which has spaces in the filename using Terminal on Mac?

I've seen some pages that say type: "open FileName" and it works for files that are one worded. But I would like to open a picture that is named: "Test Subject.jpg".

I've already tried: "open Test Subject.jpeg" and "open TestSubject.jpeg" but none will open it.

How can I open a picture or video on Terminal if there is more than one word in the "FileName" e.g. Test Subject.jpeg?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure this is a duplicate. The linked duplicate is regarding quoting around `~`, whereas this question supposes no knowledge of quoting even for spaces.

Comment: yes i could not find this anywhere on forum chats but i did end up finding out how eventually watching multiple youtube videos. Thanks though as i did get a correct answer from grg. I accidentally copied the question and put it as an answer. That explains why there is 2 answers and not just the 1 correct one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Either escape the space with a backslash or use quotes.

```
open Test\ Subject.jpg
```

```
open "Test Subject.jpg"
```

You can also use autocomplete with tab. Type `open Test` then ⇥ to autocomplete.

Take note of the extension and make sure you use the right one. You've used 3 different extensions in your question, only the right one will open the file. List the contents of the folder with `ls`.